# Angular 2/5 Smart Table with Django REST API

Tags: django, angular, django-rest-framework

I am looking for an example of a smart table that accesses an API provided by Django REST API.
Since my database is very large, it is very important to have server-side pagination and filtering.

JSON response of my API

```
{
    "count": 11512,
    "next": "http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/icd/?page=2",
    "previous": null,
    "results": [
        { ...
```

Can you help me with a little jump-start, please?

Comment: Did you try collecting results from response to angular collection and creating smart table from it?

Comment: I think I've already done that.  But then my site will take forever to load. Because the "get" command without server side pagination loads all elements into an array. I didn't make it with pagination.

Answer (score 1):

According to rest-framework documentation you can set pagination style in your `settings.py` file:

```
REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    'DEFAULT_PAGINATION_CLASS': 'rest_framework.pagination.LimitOffsetPagination',
    'PAGE_SIZE': 100
}
```

also you can set up pagination classes and set them to your Views `pagination_class` property:

```
class LargeResultsSetPagination(PageNumberPagination):
    page_size = 1000
    page_size_query_param = 'page_size'
    max_page_size = 10000

class StandardResultsSetPagination(PageNumberPagination):
    page_size = 100
    page_size_query_param = 'page_size'
    max_page_size = 1000
```

and to view:

```
class BillingRecordsView(generics.ListAPIView):
    queryset = Billing.objects.all()
    serializer_class = BillingRecordsSerializer
    pagination_class = LargeResultsSetPagination
```

Comment: And how can you get this into a filterable table on the Angular frontend?